# Flutter Amplify via Hosted web ui - How to apply Authorization code?

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using plugins `amplify_flutter: ^1.1.0` and `amplify_auth_cognito: ^1.1.0` to login to a federated IDP like Azure AD.

According to the instructions at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin_web_ui/q/platform/flutter/ I managed to get the flow working and it returns to my specified callback with an Authorization Code. But the documentation is not specifying how to apply the Authorization code to the Amplify library.

So initially, I call the Hosted web ui via

```
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI();
    print('Result ${result.isSignedIn}');
```

What should be done next to apply the Authorization code?